# Remove user from group A if they are a member of group B

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have two groups; group A and group B. If a user is part of group B, then I want to remove them from group A. This is because the groups are mutually exclusive.

I have found some scripts that will remove the user from a group, but not on the condition of the user being part of another group.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$user = "TestUser"

$groupA = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group A" -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$groupB = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group B" -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty Name

If (($groupA -contains $user) -and ($groupB -contains $user)) {
      Write-Host "$user is a member of groupA and groupB"
      Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group B" -Member $user
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through all members of Group B and (if they are a member) remove them from Group A.

```
# Get all members of the GroupB.
Foreach ($User In Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group B")
{
    # If they are a 'MemberOf' GroupA
    If ((Get-ADUser $User.SamAccountName -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf -Contains "Group A")
    {
        # Remove that user from GroupA
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group A" -Members $User.SamAccountName
    }
}
```